# Attach an instance of model within Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, activerecord

I'm creating a User model which is associated with a Cart model. At the moment the User is created, a Cart should automatically be created.

In the app, I added the call `Cart.create` into the `create` method of my `UserController`.

When I try to seed the data, however, I need to have two lines: `User.create` and `Cart.create` and attempt to make this work for only one line of `User.create`.

Is it possible to move the Cart creation code into method change (CreateUsers, Migration)?

Comment: Read about callbacks and use `after_create` callback instead. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to create a `cart` as soon as a `user` is created so you need to use callbacks for it instead of writing on the controller.

> Callbacks are methods that get called at certain moments of an object's life cycle.

So `after_create` callback will help you do what you need to do. For more details and all the callbacks you can read in [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).